# How can I access the result of a Module in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to see return true in the console.log but i can’t figure out the way to access it.

```
let funModule = (function () {
  return {
    isCuteMixin: function (obj) {
      obj.isCute = function() {
        return true
      };
    },
    singMixin: function(obj) {
      obj.sing = function() {
        console.log(“Singing to an awesome tune”);
      };
    }
  }
})();
```

I tried: `console.log(funModule.isCuteMixin(isCute));` // it doesn’t return anything… tried all of the different things. I'm definitely not doing it correctly. How would be the right to way to do it?

Comment: I took this code from https://guide.freecodecamp.org/certifications/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/object-oriented-programming/use-an-iife-to-create-a-module/

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the following function:

```
isCuteMixin: function (obj) {
  obj.isCute = function() {
    return true
  };
},
```

This function creates a new `isCute` function on the passed argument. It doesn't return anything. I would expect `console.log(funModule.isCuteMixin(isCute));` to return `undefined`.

Comment: To elaborate the answer a bit, calling `funModule.isCuteMixin(isCute)` sets the `isCute.isCute` function. After calling this you should be able to call `isCute.isCute()` which should return `true`.

Comment: Is the a way to see the results? like 
funModule.singMixin(obj);
obj.sing();

something like that

Comment: @DominickL.Bakex You can see the results by using `console.log`. The by you provided code should log `undefined` to the console. Which is the returned value.

Comment: Johan Wentholt, i tried, it is not returning anything

Comment: I Tried with funModule.isCuteMixin(isCute)and then called isCute.isCute() but, still, don't return anything.

I was doing the exercise earlier and I did get the result in the console by calling the function without using console.log but I just can't remember how I did it.

Comment: @DominickL.Bakex You should try to rephrase your question. Based on what you're saying I think you don't really understand the code that you wrote. It's hard for us to guess what you expect to see returned because the code is not broken. Try to better explain what you are hoping to achieve and maybe we can help you.